# Color faces in trimesh matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm plotting a very simple triangle using trimesh in matlab, but I struggle to find a property that could fill the triangle color.

Is there a specific one I'm missing?

The doc page doesn't say much:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trimesh.html

I'm not a big matlab expert, but I'm pretty sure there's a property for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `mesh`? Use `trimesh`!

You want a `surf`ace? Use [`trisurf`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html)!